# Intel/AMD graphics how is works

Tags: drivers, graphics, ati, fglrx

i have installed fglrx drivers from Additional drivers then at catalyst app there is 2 options intel or amd driver 
first the AMD is active by default but the graphics are glitchy during HD video or something so i activated intel, graphics is much better now i dont understand how ! AMD should be better

so,

how can i switch between cards without restarting? 
does ubuntu switch to amd automatically when needed for 3D games?
and can i configure intel card like i can configure amd catalyst
thanks

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 166c
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series] (rev ff)
    Kernel driver in use: fglrx_pci
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: Which driver did you install `fglrx` or `fglrx-updates`?

Comment: i have installed  fglrx-updates

Comment: Change it to `fglrx`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ubuntu does not switch adapters automatically.
2. You do not need to reboot to switch adapters. You can only log off and log on.
3. Your problem may be related to a wrong or badly installed AMD driver. But you did not provide any information that allows to check it.

Comment: thanks for your reply
actually i'm new at Linux world so excuse me,
so what kind of information you need 
i'm on HP pavilion g6-1320ex, im using ubuntu 14.4.3